# Delphi: Assign StatusBar.OnDrawPanel event to a thread

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I'm trying to create a backup file using a thread and the progress of the process will be indicated with a `TProgressBar` and a `TLabel` which will be dynamically created to one of the `TStatusBar` panels.

```
backup_thread:= Tbackup_thread.Create(True);
backup_thread.status_bar:= status_bar;
backup_thread.status_bar_OnDrawPanel:= status_bar.OnDrawPanel; //is it correct?
backup_thread.dir:= backup_dir;
backup_thread.OnTerminate:= backup_thread_OnTerminate;
backup_thread.Start;
```

Thread looks like this:

```
Tbackup_thread = class(TThread)
  private
    Fstatus_bar: TStatusBar;
    Fprogress_bar: TProgressBar;
    Flabel_status: TLabel;
    Fdir: String;
    Fprogress_bar_position: Word;
    Flabel_status_caption: String;
    procedure do_update_progress_bar_position;
    procedure do_update_label_status_caption;
    procedure set_object_progress_bar(const progress_bar: TProgressBar);
    procedure execute_backup;
    procedure Get_status_bar_OnDrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar; Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect); //is it correct?
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    constructor Create(CreateSuspended: Boolean);
    destructor Destroy; override;
    property status_bar: TStatusBar write Fstatus_bar;
    property status_bar_OnDrawPanel: TDrawPanelEvent read Get_status_bar_OnDrawPanel; //I get the error here...
    property dir: String write Fdir;
  end;
```

`Get_status_bar_OnDrawPanel` looks like this:

```
procedure Tbackup_thread.Get_status_bar_OnDrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar; Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect);
begin
  if Panel = Fstatus_bar.Panels[1] then
    begin
      with Fprogress_bar do begin
        Top := Rect.Top;
        Left := Rect.Left;
        Width := 60;
        Height := Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top;
      end;

      with Flabel_status do begin
        Top := Rect.Top;
        Left := Rect.Left + 105;
        Width := 150;
        Height := Rect.Bottom - Rect.Top;
      end;
    end;
end;
```

My question is how can assign from inside of thread the event `OnDrawPanel`.
Is it ok if I dynamically create the `progress_bar` and `label_status` from inside of thread and make them visible on status_bar? I believe it will work...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is how can assign from inside of thread the event OnDrawPanel.

You don't **assign** it from inside the thread, you simply **call** it if it has been assigned.  And in the case of a *drawing* event, you don't **call** it manually to begin with, you let the OS signal the main UI thread to **call** the event handler when it needs to.

> Is it ok if I dynamically create the progress_bar and label_status from inside of thread and make them visible on status_bar?

Only if you synchronize with the UI thread when you do that.  They are UI controls, afterall, and they need to be created and updated in the context of the main UI thread only.

> I believe it will work...

Not the way you have shown it, no.

I would suggest a different design.  The thread should have *no knowledge* of the status bar or label *at all*.  It should simply expose access to its progress data, and then have the main UI thread decide how to display that data as needed.  You can create new events for the thread class, just make sure you synchronize with the main UI thread when you call their handlers.

The `TThread.OnTerminate` event is a good example of this.

Try something like this:

```
type
  Tbackup_ProgressStatus_event = procedure(progress: Word; const status: String) of object;

  Tbackup_thread = class(TThread)
  private
    ...
    Fposition: Word;
    Fstatus: String;
    FOnProgressStatus: Tbackup_ProgressStatus_event;
    procedure update_progress_status(new_position: Word; const new_status: String);
    procedure do_update_progress_status;
    ...
  protected
    procedure Execute; override;
  public
    ...
    property OnProgressStatus: Tbackup_ProgressStatus_event read FOnProgressStatus write FOnProgressStatus;
  end;

procedure Tbackup_thread.Execute;
begin
  ...
  update_progress_status(..., ...);
  ...
end;

procedure Tbackup_thread.update_progress_status(new_position: Word; const new_status: String);
begin
  Fposition := new_position;
  Fstatus := new_status;
  if Assigned(FOnProgressStatus) then
    Synchronize(do_update_progress_status);
end;

procedure Tbackup_thread.do_update_progress_status;
begin
  if Assigned(FOnProgressStatus) then
    FOnProgressStatus(Fposition, Fstatus);
end;
```

```
backup_thread := Tbackup_thread.Create(True);
backup_thread.dir := backup_dir;
backup_thread.OnStatus := backup_thread_OnProgressStatus;
backup_thread.OnTerminate := backup_thread_OnTerminate;
backup_thread.Start;

...

procedure TMyForm.backup_thread_OnProgressStatus(progress: Word; const status: String);
begin
  // use progress and status as needed...
  progress_bar.Position := progress;
  label.Caption := status;
end;

procedure TMyForm.status_bar_OnDrawPanel(StatusBar: TStatusBar; Panel: TStatusPanel; const Rect: TRect);
begin
  // DRAW the specified TStatusPanel content within the specified TRect as needed...
  // DO NOT do anything else here!  Resizing controls DOES NOT belong in a
  // DRAWING event!  Do it before you even start the thread...
  //
  // Personally, I would not bother putting TProgressBar/TLabel controls
  // inside a TStatusPanel to begin with.  I would instead use THIS event
  // to DRAW a progress bar and text directly onto the Sender.Canvas
  // within the TRect using things like Sender.Canvas.FillRect() and
  // Sender.Canvas.TextRect()...
end;
```

Comment: Works! Thanks Remy for the solution and for you time!